# Using IIS Express to host a website

Tags: iis, localhost, webmatrix

I saw that this question asked before but still I didn't get my answer.
I'm trying to call my page from other device (not my laptop) I follow the instruction that I already read here and those are my steps:
1)
I changed the lines at my "applicationhost" file by the commends:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:80/ user=everyone
```

and then:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://stephanmaimon:8080/ user=everyone
```

and now my "applicationhost" file look like this:

```
<sites>
        <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:stephanmaimon" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="EmptySite" id="2">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\Stephan Maimon\Documents\My Web Sites\EmptySite" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55436:stephanmaimon" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

And now my WebMatrix setting look like [this](http://screencast.com/t/f5jbw9yNuH5), but when I press "run" 
I get this error -

> Cannot start the website because administrative privileges are required to bind to the hostname or port.
>   Recommendations:
>   1. Replace "hostname" with "localhost".

and now I stuck....
Please help me out, thanks

Comment: I'm running into that issue now with Visual Studio 2015 RC and Windows 10. The only workaround I have right now is running Visual Studio in administrator mode, so you could try running WebMatrix in admin mode. I'm not a fan of having to do this every time I start up, but hopefully this at least gets you running on your feet if you haven't already. If you have gotten it running, what did you do?